# Do local variables need to be initialized if they are going to be written to (before first read)?

Tags: c#

I saw a lot of code with the following structure:

```
public void Blah()
{
    int a = 0;
    string b = "";
    DateTime c = DateTime.MinValue;
    bool d = false;
    // ...More initializations with dummy values

    // Overwrite the values in a, b, c, d, e.g. a = ReturnInt();

    // Do calculations, reading the values from a, b, c, d, like DoCalculations(a);
}
```

In general I much prefer something like:

```
public void Blah()
{
    int a = GetInt();
    string b = GetString();
    DateTime c = GetDateTime();
    bool d = GetBool();

    // Do calculations, reading the values from a, b, c, d, like DoCalculations(a);
}
```

Is that really necessary and will there any performance hits due to the extra initializations?

Comment: You can do #2, no problem

Comment: @rikitikitik Yes I have tried that out but I am really curious why people make that extra variable initializations

Comment: It might be slightly unrelated, but if your intent is to "throw away" the value later in favour of overwriting the value sometime later via `ReturnInt()`, then definitely do _not_ give it an initial value because the compiler will not allow you to accidentally read its initial throw-away value accidentally. I see that often done using `out` methods (like `Int32.TryParse`) or if they're being written to in a lower scope (declared/used outside an `if` or loop, but assigned within the if/loop) and it's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables should be initialized before use only if that use is a `read` if you are going to overwrite it immediately after initialization, it is **better to follow the 2nd style** you show, mainly for **readability purposes**, I expect performance hit (from style #1) if any would be typically minimal.

Comment: I agree...The second style is much more readable. And yet, I saw in numerous occasions (from different projects) that people are using the first style! That's what strikes me most

Comment: @rexcfnghk it could be a mandated code style, or the code has been changed from what originally needed style #1, or if there are conditionals with branches which read without writing..

Answer (score -1):

Initializing variables is a common standard used by many developers.

Initializing variables is done because depending on the language and environment, reading uninitialized variables may yield undefined behavior.  And because the exact conditions where variables may or may not be initialized automatically is difficult to remember, people tend to simply *always* initialize objects before using them.

It is generally considered a good practice to perform this initialization in the constructor.

It is also specifically mentioned in Scott Meyers' very popular book **Effective C++**.

- **Item 4:  Make sure objects are initialized before they're used.**

Comment: On second glance, I agree that I failed to answer the exact question posed.

What I forgot to say, was that the people writing such code probably do so by habit due to the standard I mentioned.

As for which is better, I would pick the second, as I cannot think of any reason to suffer the runtime cost of initializing the variable and then immediately changing its value.